# Should all custom QML components have "Item" as their root element?

Tags: qml

This is a best practices question. In QML, is it preferable to use the Item type as the root element for all custom QML components or is it acceptable to use say, Rectangle, ColumnLayout, or anything else as the root element? After all, Rectangle and ColumnLayout inherit from Item so in a sense, if either one of those are used, its still an Item root element. Are there any known drawbacks for not using the actual Item QML type (base type) as a custom component's root element?

Answer (score 1):

No. You should use whatever works best for your requirements. There are things to keep in mind for users of that components (such as [default properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#default-properties), [sizing behaviour](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#implicitWidth-prop), etc.), but nothing that says you should use `Item` as the root element.

Comment: Yeah, actually the root of inheritance in QML is [QtObject QML Type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qtobject.html). Using [Item QML Type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html) for non-GUI related things like constants storage or data source management is an overkill and anti-pattern.

Comment: I know, given that how QML is presented and marketed, it is weird to realize, but matter of the fact is that QML components **don't have to be** related to GUI. There is nothing in QML itself which would force components to be something drawable — only particular base types in QtQuick library do that. No technical restrictions should stop you from designing a web server QML Type, or declare SQL connection properties etc.

Comment: Talking about a web server, in fact there's a [DBus connection plugin](https://git.sailfishos.org/mer-core/nemo-qml-plugin-dbus/blob/master/tests/auto/tst_dbus_interface.qml), and it's being tested with QtTest framework — 100% pure QML API, no drawable items involved.

Comment: @ratijas Yes, and I have deployed [QML daemons](https://github.com/michpolicht/CuteHMI/tree/master/extensions/CuteHMI/Examples/CountDaemon.3).